Trouble integrating Sentry distributed tracing in NestJS microservices
I'm encountering difficulty integrating Sentry distributed tracing into my NestJS microservices architecture. My setup involves a NestJS API gateway communicating with multiple Nest microservices (A, B, etc.). I've successfully integrated Sentry into each service and begun catching exceptions. However, I'm now attempting to integrate distributed tracing to trace errors across these services.
Despite following the documentation, I've run into issues as many of the methods mentioned are deprecated, and the examples provided for Node.js aren't sufficiently clear.
Could someone provide guidance or a clearer example on how to implement distributed tracing with Sentry in a NestJS microservices environment, considering the deprecated methods and the nuances of Node.js? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
// I tried to create a transaction from the sentry instance
  const transaction = this.sentryService.instance().startTransaction({
        name: 'Updating Test',
      });

// passing the sentryTrace for the microservices  
const data = await firstValueFrom(
        this.clientOfServiceA
          .send(
            { cmd: "update-test" },
            {
              body,
              sentryTrace: transaction.toTraceparent(),
            },
          )
      );


// In service A, I tried to continue the trace from the sentryTrace provided as payload to the service
this.sentryService.instance().continueTrace({
      sentryTrace: sentryTrace,
      baggage: 'test',
    });

